# Error message while updating

Tags: updates, kubuntu, hosts

I am using Kubuntu 18.04.2, I opened terminal and entered the following command to update:

```
sudo apt update
```

It produced the following result:

```
[sudo] password for aayush: 
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                   
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease               
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]         
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [17.9 kB]
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]      
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [25.6 kB]
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [658 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons [59.3 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [36.1 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [16.4 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [104 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 128x128 Icons [149 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Get:15 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [544 kB]
Ign:16 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
42% [Connecting to in.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.24)]                                        
42% [Connecting to in.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.24)]                                        


Ign:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons               
Ign:19 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-upd                                           ates/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons
Ign:20 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:21 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:22 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Ign:24 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:25 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 128x128 Icons
Ign:26 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:27 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Ign:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:19 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons
Ign:20 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:21 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:22 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Ign:24 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:25 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 128x128 Icons
Ign:26 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:27 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Err:17 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
  Connection failed [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Connection failed [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:19 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons
  Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::19), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.31), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.26), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.23), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.24), connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err:20 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err:21 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err:22 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err:23 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err:24 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err:25 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 128x128 Icons
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err:26 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Ign:27 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Err:27 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Fetched 1,866 kB in 6min 30s (4,784 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar  Connection failed [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Connection failed [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar  Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::19), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.31), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.26), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.23), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.24), connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/universe/dep11/icons-128x128.tar  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
aayush@aayush-desktop-edu:~$ 
::1                 ip6-allrouters
aayush-desktop-edu  ip6-localhost
fe00::0             ip6-localnet
ff00::0             ip6-loopback
ff02::1             ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::2             localhost
ip6-allnodes        
aayush@aayush-desktop-edu:~$ sd
sd: command not found
```

I know my internet connection is weak due to which the command failed to update software list but the last few lines of this message contains information available in hosts file. Is there any malware in my system? Why has it produced such message?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it. but one thing that can allow you to check would be running the top command to see if any unusual processes are running.

```
top
```

Comment: Why this message contains hosts file information after the line "aayush@aayush-desktop-edu:~$"?